# Highchart scrollbar and two x axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scrollbar

I have a little problem with my meteogram which I created in highchart. I have two x axises (on the top and on the bottom of my chart). I enabled scrollbar (I'm using highstock) and this scrollbar affected only on my bottom axis. When I move my scroll only bottom axis scrolls. I also want to move my top axis. How to do that? There is no 'scroll' option in reference to axis, only global:

```
scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    }
```

Here you can see how it looks like:
[image]

Top categories doesn't change when we move scroll. Only bottom are changing.

Here is code resposible for x axises creation:

```
xAxis: [ {
        categories: prepareCategories(jsonData),
        min: 0,
        max: 25,
        tickInterval: 8,
        tickWidth: 2,
        plotLines: preparePlotLines(jsonData)
    }, {
        categories: prepareWindCategories(jsonData),
        min: 0,
        max: 25,
        tickInterval: 2,
        tickWidth: 2,
        opposite: true,
        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return prepareWindLabel(this.value.wind, this.value.windDirection);
            }
        }
    } ],
```

Comment: I would think that linking the two axes would be the way to do it - look at the linkedTo property for second axis.

Comment: Yeah, it's working! Thanks for your help.